# Ссылка отображается как url

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Делал фильтр который выводит строки из бд и делает редирект по url, все работает но проблема с jquery, у меня кнопка это по сути ссылка которая перебрасывает на url из бд, так вот я прописал значение которое добавляется из бд href=url , то есть после выбора строк выводится в кнопу(ссылку) вместо "Подобрать" само значение из бд то есть url,а нужно чтобы всегда было слово "Подобрать" вот код:

```js
$('#idcat2').change(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'templates/megawebshop/html/com_virtuemart/category/show2.php',
    data: {
      'url': val
    },
    success: function(data) {
      var obj = JSON.parse(data);
      obj.forEach(function(item) {
        $('#redirect').attr("href", item).text(item);
      })
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<a id="redirect" type="submit" name="submit" value="Кнопка">Подобрать</a>
```

Comment: `$('#redirect').attr("href",item).text(item);` здесь text лишнее

Comment: `<a id="redirect"  type="submit" name="submit" value="Кнопка" >Подобрать</a>` а зедсь type, name, value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a id="redirect" type="submit" name="submit" value="Кнопка">Подобрать</a>
```

Переделываем

```
<a id="redirect" href="#">Подобрать</a>
```

Далее это переделываем:

```
success: function(data) {
    $('#redirect').attr("href",data);
}
```

Далее нужно чтобы `ajax` возвращал `url`, я уже ответил как это сделать.

Answer (score 2):

Как то так

```
$('#idcat2').change(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'templates/megawebshop/html/com_virtuemart/category/show2.php',
        data: {'url': val},
        success: function(data) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(data);
            obj.forEach(function(item) {
                $('#redirect').attr("href",item);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

И ссылка соответственно

```
<a id="redirect" href="#">Подобрать</a>
```

Comment: Ух, во что ты ввязался :D

Comment: @Manitikyl я вообще так понимаю он весь код за счёт стака пишет XD уже какой вопрос по одному и тому же проекту=)

Comment: Нет ) Вариант с ссылкой я сам придумал!